# how to simulate suspended state for iOS app?

Tags: ios

I'm testing silent push notification when it wakes up the app and move it form suspended state to background state. Is there a way to simulate that state?

Comment: Press the home button and then send a push to your device.

Comment: The app becomes in Background state not suspended

Comment: No, the app will briefly enter background state and then become suspended. Suspended is the state where the app is in memory but not in the foreground and not executing in the background.

Comment: what happen if get any event/notification in suspended state?

Comment: @HossamGhareeb did you figure out how to simulate the suspended (as opposed to background state) for iOS app? This is even harder in iOS 13 with scenes staying in the background state almost indefinitely, in the simulator at least. Thanks